# Loading MySQL data into a PHP array

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to load a list of IDs into a PHP array which I can loop through. The SQL query I am using returns 283 rows when I run it in PHPMyAdmin. However, when I run the following PHP script, it only returns a single row (the first row). How can I modify my code to include all the rows from the resulting SQL query in my PHP array?

Code:

```
//Get active listing IDs 
$active = "SELECT L_ListingID FROM `markers`";
$active = mysql_query($active) or die(mysql_error());

if(is_resource($active) and mysql_num_rows($active)>0){
$row = mysql_fetch_array($active);
print_r($row);
};
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using mysql_fetch_array will return only the first row and then advance the internal counter. You need to implement it as part of a loop like the following to get what you want.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($active)) {
 // Your code here
}
```

Keep in mind that mysql_ functions are now also deprecated and slated to be removed in future version of php. Use mysqli_ functions or PDO.

Comment: How could I write the same function using PDO instead?

Answer (score 4):

In PDO it's rather straight forward:

```
$rows = $conn->query($active)->fetchAll();
```

See [`PDO::query`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/PDO.query) and [`PDOStatement::fetchAll`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/PDOStatement.fetchAll).

Answer (score 2):

With `mysqli` you would use [mysqli_result::fetch_all](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) and with `PDO` there's [PDOStatement::fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.fetchall.php) to fetch all rows into an array.

Code for mysqli

```
$sql = "SELECT L_ListingID FROM `markers`";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
if ($result !== false) {
    $rows = $result->fetch_all();
}
```

with PDO it's nearly the same

```
$sql = "SELECT L_ListingID FROM `markers`";
$result = $pdo->query($sql);
if ($result !== false) {
    $rows = $result->fetchAll();
}
```